# Which command in the Linux/UNIX sh shell returns my current directory?

Tags: linux, sh

Using the `sh` shell (not `bash`), which command in Linux/UNIX prints out my current directory?

```
$ *showmewhereiam*
/sys/kernel/debug
$
```

Comment: @Mad-scientist While this may be true, it defeats the purpose of a question/answer site to tell people to go to Google. [90% of our traffic is from web searches](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2445/why-dont-people-upvote-when-browsing-the-site/2449#2449).

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try `pwd`.

```
$ pwd
/home/<username>
```

Comment: when i first touch linux, i thought it's a command about **password** and `/dev` is something about development (source codes or something like that)

Comment: Oh, dev means device?! Always thought up until now it just meant dev... I thought dev/null was where linux **developers** put the special null object. Thanks @LiuYan刘研

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 - I totally agree it's confusing if you don't know. I had to look it up. It stands for "Print Working Directory" for anyone else who's baffled by why they would choose that command for that functionality.

Comment: @squarecandy, That's why I will avoid using acronyms as possible as I can when grown older and older, even the acronym doesn't have ambiguous meaning at this time -- You never know what meaning it will have in the future. There's a joke said by [Jeff Dunham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Dunham)'s doll Walter: [What happens in D.C. stays on YouTube!](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0088408/quotes), where D.C. means **D**igital **C**amera but also means Washington, **D**istrict of **C**olumbia in the joke.

Answer (score 13):

While the general answer is `pwd`, note that this may give different results depending on how you reached a given directory, and whether the route included symbolic links.

For instance, if you have a directory called `real` and a symbolic link to that directory called `virtual`, and you `cd` to the `virtual` directory, then `pwd` will show that `virtual` directory name, even though the actual directory you are in is `real`.

To show the real underlying directory, use either `pwd -P` or `readlink -f` (for a arbitrary path):

```
$ mkdir real
$ ln -s real virtual
$ cd virtual
$ pwd
/home/username/tmp/virtual
$ pwd -P
/home/username/tmp/real
$ readlink -f .
/home/username/tmp/real
```

Note that shells often replace the `pwd` command with their own internal version, so on my system (RHEL6), even though the `pwd(1)` manual page suggests that `--physical` will work as well as `-P`, because I'm running `bash`, it doesn't:

```
$ pwd --physical
bash: pwd: --: invalid option
pwd: usage: pwd [-LP]
$ /bin/pwd --physical
/home/username/tmp/real
$ /usr/bin/env pwd --physical
/home/username/tmp/real
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ pwd
/your/current/directory
$
```

`pwd` comes from the **print working directory**.

## From Linux man page:

> ## Name
>
> **pwd** - print name of current/working directory
>
> ## Synopsis
>
> **pwd** [OPTION]...
>
> ## Description
>
> Print the full filename of the current working directory.
>
> **-L**, **--logical**
>
> use PWD from environment, even if it contains symlinks
>
> **-P**, **--physical**
>
> avoid all symlinks
>
> **--help**
>
> display this help and exit
>
> **--version**
>
> output version information and exit
>
> NOTE: your shell may have its own version of pwd, which usually supersedes the version described here. Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports.
>
> (...)

Comment: This duplicates information in [the accepted answer from over five years ago](http://superuser.com/a/300045/461558). Can you add anything else?

Answer (score 1):

As others said, `pwd` usually does the job well enough. However, I'd like to add an idea which has helped me out.

On all shells in common use today, you're able to customize the appearance of the command prompt. I like to customize mine so that it shows me both the name of the computer I'm on and my working directory. That way, I always know where I am. (The computer name part helps me realize if the terminal window I'm using has been used to SSH into a remote server.) For example, when I open a new terminal window on my laptop, which I call Plastico, I see this:

```
Plastico ~> cd Desktop/
Plastico ~/Desktop> cd ~/Sites/raygunrobot.com
Plastico ~/Sites/raygunrobot.com> cd /usr
Plastico /usr>
```

You can see that it's abbreviating my home directory as `~`. I find doing this for my terminal prompts is incredibly handy - I always know at a glance exactly where I am, even more so than I would by looking at a Finder window.

On tcsh, I do this by adding `set prompt = 'Plastico %~%# '`
 to my .tcshrc file in my home directory. I've done it on ksh too by adding `export PS1="Plastico $PWD $ "` to my .profile file. But being a Linux user, you probably use Bash, which I don't have much experience with (I'm a weirdo like that). But [it looks like](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) I might be able to do it by adding `PS1="Plastico \w $ "` to my .bashrc file.

**Edit:** Just noticed the OP states you're interested in sh, not bash. Oh well; hope folks find this useful regardless.

Comment: That's a cool idea. Might work well for a simple desktop use case. Seems like it might get unwieldily for for super deep directories if your prompt alone is `Plastico /var/www/vhosts/myveryexcellentwebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/myveryexcellenttheme/js/vendor/excellentjs/ >` or something like that.